# pointcut in Spring AOP to all method calls within a given method

Tags: spring, aop

Let's say I have a method and I want to track his "content", I mean all (or a selection of) the calls to the other classes within that method. To give an example I have:

```
public void myMethod() {
myClassInstance.method1();
anotherClassInstance.method2();
}
```

And I want my advice to be executed for method1 and method2. Is that possible?

It is possible to define something like "pointcut for all the methods have a common method in the stacktrace"?

Thanks,

Comment: No it isn't. There are only before, after or arround a method pointcuts

Comment: what I meant is define something like "around all the methods invoked in myMethod"

Comment: No there isn't something like that.